What is the best mixed model approach for a time series of animal attack records?
I have a dataset of animal attack records for Brazilian states between the years 2007 and 2022. I have three explanatory variables, which were standardized for the analyses. To incorporate the temporal autocorrelation of the data into a mixed model, I thought about using a glmmPQL (MASS package) with Poisson distribution (count data). As this analysis does not allow obtaining AIC values, I thought about checking the residuals visually to evaluate the best autocorrelation structure for the model. The structure of the model would be as follows. I obtained the R^2 values ​​using the r.squaredGLMM function, but it gives two different R^2 values ​​(see below). As this is the first time I've used a mixed model with temporal autocorrelation, I wanted to know if I'm heading in the right direction.
model <- glmmPQL(attacks~x1 + x2 + x3,random=~1|ID,data=envir,family=poisson, correlation=corGaus(form = ~ year|ID))
###The "ID" represents the Brazilian states and "year" represents the number of attacks for each year (2007-2022) and for each state.
plot(model)#to check residuals
r.squaredGLMM(model)#package MuMIn
           R2m       R2c

delta     0.6348790 0.9995354
lognormal 0.6348793 0.9995358
trigamma  0.6348788 0.9995350

If you are interested in selecting among time series models where the outcomes are counts, you may want to look at the {mvgam} R package. This package fits Bayesian Dynamic Generalized Additive Models and was designed for dealing with non-Gaussian time series while including latent dynamic processes, such as autoregressive, Random Walk or Gaussian Processes. It also provides methods to guide model selection via approximate leave-one-out cross-validation or approximate leave-future-out cross-validation.
Below I show an example of the modeling pipeline for the package using some simulated autocorrelated count time series. There are plenty of other examples in the package vignettes, which you can access from the 'Articles' menu on the package website, and on my blog (see for example Temporal autocorrelation in GAMs and the mvgam package and Distributed lags (and hierarchical distributed lags) using mgcv and mvgam).
# Load packages
library(ggplot2); theme_set(theme_bw())
library(marginaleffects)
library(mvgam)
packageVersion('mvgam')
#> [1] '1.1.3'

# Simulate 4 time series of counts that include varying intercepts,
# hierarchical seasonal patterns and AR1 dynamics
set.seed(55)
dat <- sim_mvgam(n_series = 4,
                 mu = c(0.5, 1, 1.5, 2),
                 seasonality = 'hierarchical',
                 family = poisson(),
                 trend_model = AR(p = 1),
                 prop_trend = 0.55)

# The simulated data are split into training and testing folds
str(dat)
#> List of 6
#>  $ data_train        :'data.frame':  300 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ y     : int [1:300] 0 3 1 12 0 4 2 10 1 3 ...
#>   ..$ season: int [1:300] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
#>   ..$ year  : int [1:300] 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
#>   ..$ series: Factor w/ 4 levels "series_1","series_2",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#>   ..$ time  : int [1:300] 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 ...
#>  $ data_test         :'data.frame':  100 obs. of  5 variables:
#>   ..$ y     : int [1:100] 0 1 8 11 0 5 10 8 2 1 ...
#>   ..$ season: int [1:100] 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 6 6 ...
#>   ..$ year  : int [1:100] 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 ...
#>   ..$ series: Factor w/ 4 levels "series_1","series_2",..: 1 2 3 4 1 2 3 4 1 2 ...
#>   ..$ time  : int [1:100] 76 76 76 76 77 77 77 77 78 78 ...
#>  $ true_corrs        : num [1:4, 1:4] 1 -0.03877 -0.20608 -0.00979 -0.03877 ...
#>  $ true_trends       : num [1:100, 1:4] -0.00844 0.31037 0.219 -0.0421 -0.87874 ...
#>  $ global_seasonality: num [1:100] 0.556 -0.164 -0.345 -0.756 -1.391 ...
#>  $ trend_params      :List of 3
#>   ..$ ar1: num [1:4] 0.0601 -0.9062 0.0758 -0.5596
#>   ..$ ar2: num [1:4] 0 0 0 0
#>   ..$ ar3: num [1:4] 0 0 0 0
dplyr::glimpse(dat$data_train)
#> Rows: 300
#> Columns: 5
#> $ y      <int> 0, 3, 1, 12, 0, 4, 2, 10, 1, 3, 3, 5, 1, 0, 6, 7, 0, 2, 1, 7, 0…
#> $ season <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, …
#> $ year   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, …
#> $ series <fct> series_1, series_2, series_3, series_4, series_1, series_2, ser…
#> $ time   <int> 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, …

# Visualise all of the time series
plot_mvgam_series(data = dat$data_train, series = 'all')


# Look at features for just one time series
plot_mvgam_series(data = dat$data_train, series = 1)


# Fit a poorly specified model that ignores the temporal dynamics
# but that models the seasonality and varying intercepts
mod1 <- mvgam(y ~ 
                # Hierarchical intercepts i.e. (1 | series)
                s(series, bs = 're') +
                # Shared seasonal pattern
                s(season, bs = 'cc', k = 8) +
                # Seasonal deviations
                s(season, series, bs = 'sz', k = 5),
              # Boundaries to ensure the seasonal smooth joins
              # in the correct place
              knots = list(season = c(0.5, 12.5)),
              # Training data
              data = dat$data_train,
          # Evaluation data
          newdata = dat$data_test,
              family = poisson(),
              silent = 1)
#> Compiling Stan program using cmdstanr
#> Start sampling
#> Running MCMC with 4 parallel chains...
#> 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 finished in 5.6 seconds.
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 finished in 6.2 seconds.
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 finished in 6.4 seconds.
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 finished in 6.7 seconds.
#> 
#> All 4 chains finished successfully.
#> Mean chain execution time: 6.2 seconds.
#> Total execution time: 7.0 seconds.

# Model summary
summary(mod1, include_betas = FALSE)
#> GAM formula:
#> y ~ s(season, bs = "cc", k = 8) + s(season, series, bs = "sz", 
#>     k = 5) + s(series, bs = "re")
#> 
#> Family:
#> poisson
#> 
#> Link function:
#> log
#> 
#> Trend model:
#> None
#> 
#> N series:
#> 4 
#> 
#> N timepoints:
#> 100 
#> 
#> Status:
#> Fitted using Stan 
#> 4 chains, each with iter = 1000; warmup = 500; thin = 1 
#> Total post-warmup draws = 2000
#> 
#> 
#> GAM coefficient (beta) estimates:
#>              2.5% 50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> (Intercept) -0.73 1.5   3.6    1  1212
#> 
#> GAM group-level estimates:
#>                  2.5%    50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> mean(s(series)) -1.90 -0.029   1.8    1  1479
#> sd(s(series))    0.19  0.960   3.2    1   785
#> 
#> Approximate significance of GAM smooths:
#>                    edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
#> s(season)        5.360      6  87.07  <2e-16 ***
#> s(season,series) 7.179      5   5.83    0.59    
#> s(series)        0.539      4   0.00    1.00    
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Stan MCMC diagnostics:
#> n_eff / iter looks reasonable for all parameters
#> Rhat looks reasonable for all parameters
#> 6 of 2000 iterations ended with a divergence (0.3%)
#>  *Try running with larger adapt_delta to remove the divergences
#> 0 of 2000 iterations saturated the maximum tree depth of 12 (0%)
#> E-FMI indicated no pathological behavior
#> 
#> Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Thu Jul 04 9:36:57 AM 2024.
#> For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
#> and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split MCMC chains
#> (at convergence, Rhat = 1)

# Plot the estimated effects from the model
conditional_effects(mod1, type = 'link')


# Extract and plot hindcasts and forecasts
fc1 <- forecast(mod1)
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
plot(fc1, series = 1)
plot(fc1, series = 2)
plot(fc1, series = 3)
plot(fc1, series = 4)


layout(1)

# Clearly the model is missing some temporal autocorrelation
plot(mod1, type = 'residuals', series = 1)


plot(mod1, type = 'residuals', series = 2)


plot(mod1, type = 'residuals', series = 3)


plot(mod1, type = 'residuals', series = 4)


# Now fit a model that includes latent AR1 residuals
mod2 <- mvgam(y ~ 
                # All as for mod1
                s(series, bs = 're') +
                s(season, bs = 'cc', k = 8) +
                s(season, series, bs = 'sz', k = 5),
              knots = list(season = c(0.5, 12.5)),
              data = dat$data_train,
          newdata = dat$data_test,
              family = poisson(),
              
              # Add AR1 residuals
              trend_model = AR(p = 1),
              noncentred = TRUE,
              silent = 1)
#> Compiling Stan program using cmdstanr
#> Start sampling
#> Running MCMC with 4 parallel chains...
#> 
#> Chain 1 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration:   1 / 1000 [  0%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 100 / 1000 [ 10%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 200 / 1000 [ 20%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 300 / 1000 [ 30%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 400 / 1000 [ 40%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 500 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Warmup) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 501 / 1000 [ 50%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 600 / 1000 [ 60%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 700 / 1000 [ 70%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 800 / 1000 [ 80%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 1 finished in 20.9 seconds.
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 900 / 1000 [ 90%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 2 finished in 22.7 seconds.
#> Chain 4 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 4 finished in 23.0 seconds.
#> Chain 3 Iteration: 1000 / 1000 [100%]  (Sampling) 
#> Chain 3 finished in 23.7 seconds.
#> 
#> All 4 chains finished successfully.
#> Mean chain execution time: 22.6 seconds.
#> Total execution time: 24.1 seconds.

# Model summary and conditional effect estimates
summary(mod2, include_betas = FALSE)
#> GAM formula:
#> y ~ s(season, bs = "cc", k = 8) + s(season, series, bs = "sz", 
#>     k = 5) + s(series, bs = "re")
#> 
#> Family:
#> poisson
#> 
#> Link function:
#> log
#> 
#> Trend model:
#> AR(p = 1)
#> 
#> N series:
#> 4 
#> 
#> N timepoints:
#> 100 
#> 
#> Status:
#> Fitted using Stan 
#> 4 chains, each with iter = 1000; warmup = 500; thin = 1 
#> Total post-warmup draws = 2000
#> 
#> 
#> GAM coefficient (beta) estimates:
#>              2.5% 50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> (Intercept) -0.72 1.3   3.6    1  1319
#> 
#> GAM group-level estimates:
#>                 2.5%   50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> mean(s(series)) -1.9 0.002   1.8    1  1867
#> sd(s(series))    0.3 0.890   2.8    1   703
#> 
#> Approximate significance of GAM smooths:
#>                   edf Ref.df Chi.sq p-value    
#> s(season)        5.14      6  33.36 4.4e-06 ***
#> s(season,series) 3.93      5   0.45   0.980    
#> s(series)        2.47      4  12.42   0.084 .  
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
#> 
#> Latent trend parameter AR estimates:
#>            2.5%   50% 97.5% Rhat n_eff
#> ar1[1]   -0.200  0.29  0.92 1.01   328
#> ar1[2]   -0.690 -0.16  0.19 1.00   308
#> ar1[3]   -0.041  0.47  0.96 1.01   332
#> ar1[4]   -0.980 -0.66 -0.21 1.01   490
#> sigma[1]  0.470  0.71  1.00 1.00   632
#> sigma[2]  0.570  0.77  1.00 1.00   704
#> sigma[3]  0.340  0.48  0.66 1.00   570
#> sigma[4]  0.290  0.39  0.53 1.00   730
#> 
#> Stan MCMC diagnostics:
#> n_eff / iter looks reasonable for all parameters
#> Rhat looks reasonable for all parameters
#> 1 of 2000 iterations ended with a divergence (0.05%)
#>  *Try running with larger adapt_delta to remove the divergences
#> 0 of 2000 iterations saturated the maximum tree depth of 12 (0%)
#> E-FMI indicated no pathological behavior
#> 
#> Samples were drawn using NUTS(diag_e) at Thu Jul 04 9:38:03 AM 2024.
#> For each parameter, n_eff is a crude measure of effective sample size,
#> and Rhat is the potential scale reduction factor on split MCMC chains
#> (at convergence, Rhat = 1)
conditional_effects(mod2, type = 'link')


# Plot the AR1 dynamics for each series
layout(matrix(1:4, ncol = 2))
plot(mod2, type = 'trend', series = 1)
plot(mod2, type = 'trend', series = 2)
plot(mod2, type = 'trend', series = 3)
plot(mod2, type = 'trend', series = 4)


layout(1)

# Compare models based on their in-sample LOO fits; a higher
# score is better, and here mod2 is much higher than mod1
suppressWarnings(loo_compare(mod1, mod2))
#>      elpd_diff se_diff
#> mod2    0.0       0.0 
#> mod1 -176.4      46.4

# Compare models based on forecast accuracies, using the 
# Continuous Rank Probability Score
fc2 <- forecast(mod2)
scores1 <- score(fc1)
scores2 <- score(fc2)

# For each series, is the AR1 model's forecast better (lower
# CRPS)?
for(i in 1:4){
  print(sum(scores2[[i]]$score) < sum(scores1[[i]]$score))  
}
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] TRUE
#> [1] TRUE

# See ?mvgam::lfo.cv for a more comprehensive method to compare forecasts
# that uses approximate leave-future-out cross-validation 

Created on 2024-07-04 with reprex v2.1.0
